# How to access Groovy script from SAP CPI Script Collection in another Script?

Tags: groovy, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cpi

I try to access a groovy script from a script collection in another script (SAP CPI). The script from the script collection contains an enumeration and I want to access this enumeration in a message mapping script. So I do the following:

1. Create the script in the script collection (same package as the iFlow)
   [image]
2. Reference the script in the integration flow
   [image]
3. Import the enumeration and use it (it's a script function used in message mapping)
   [image]
4. Simulate the mapping (which works if I copy enum to mapping script as well)
   [image]

> Runtime exception during processing target field mapping /ns1:Messages/ns1:Message1/PerPhone/PerPhone/phoneType. The root message is: Exception:[com.sap.aii.mappingtool.tf7.rt.BehaviorInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BonusScheme for class: Script29] in class com.sap.aii.mappingtool.tf7.ScriptHandler method addPicklistValue[[Ljava.lang.String;@1e57ab7f, [Ljava.lang.String;@29c56946, [Ljava.lang.String;@11ba6ab8, [Ljava.lang.String;@3d2f6b53, [Ljava.lang.String;@1e0033da, com.sap.aii.mappingtool.tf7.rt.ResultListImpl@1c8de605, com.sap.xi.mapping.camel.impl.MappingContextImpl@470ff907, com.sap.aii.mappingtool.tf7.rt.Context@5e20a086] on the exchange: Exchange[ID-ff2d2c8d-4286-4e5a-5b75-1556-1657430698694-1068-1]

Seems that my enumeration isn't known and therefore can't be referenced. I'm just asking myself - why? It's everything deployed. Someone has an idea?

Comment: Don't know how the classloader working in sap-cpi, but in plain groovy each script is a class where classname=filename. So, inside integration package you have "enumerations" class and probably there you have nested enum class ..

Answer (score 0):

I think You cannot reference a Script from Script Collection in a Messaging Mapping.
Even if you want to reuse a Common Script like getHeaders or getProperties Script as Custom Function from a Script Collection, You cannot.
it's just the way it was built.